# Why even use Strings in hashes if symbols exist

Tags: ruby

Why would I use a string if using a symbol 1) saves memory 2) has a better access time

I saw code in which sometimes Strings are used and sometimes symbols. Why would you go for Strings having all the advantages with symbols?

OK, your access keys often won't be strings so you would always type the casting. But then, why does the casting not happen implicitly?

Comment: When the thing that will reference the key is always starting as a string, I suppose it's worth keeping them as strings. Also, I've recently had to use integers as keys. They're not able to cast as symbols (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Having a number as key is actually a good point

Comment: You know that the keys can be anything, right? Classes, strings, arrays, hashes, symbols, procs, ... Why make a special exception for strings?

Comment: No I didn't, thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different tradeoffs,

- Symbols are best used for a bounded set of keys that are ideally limited to values found in the source code.
- String are best used for an unbounded set of keys that are taken from user input or other external sources, like for when processing unstructured JSON data.

Why?

Before Ruby 2.2 symbols are not garbage collected and dealing with an unbounded set of keys obviously leads to a memory leak. But even with garage collection there is still a significant cost of having to "intern" all string input to turn them into symbols. And it can thus be smartest to just use string keys if your code consumes strings from text files or the web anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> I saw code in which sometimes Strings are used and sometimes symbols. Why would you go for Strings having all the advantages with symbols?

Before [Symbol GC](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9634) was added in Ruby 2.2, generating a symbol at runtime would cause a memory leak for long running applications. Using strings was a way to circumvent this memory issue and get gc, and it lingers around the ruby ecosystem. With frozen string support, at some point symbols and strings will be identical.

> OK, your access keys often won't be strings so you would always type the casting. But then, why does the casting not happen implicitly?

A hash maps an object to an object. This:

```
{"a"=>1, :a=>1}
```

is a valid hash.

If you want to cast implicitly you could use [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)  from ActiveSupport.

Comment: In which scenario would you want a key accessible with "a" and :a .. sounds more like a edgy edge case which causes more troubles than it solves

Comment: That last sentence is misleading "with frozen string support, at some point symbols and strings will be identical"—there are big difference between a symbol and immutable strings, there is guaranteed to be only one instance of `:abc` but there can be many instances of `"abc"` and hence also the significant runtime effort of interning strings to symbols. Which is still a very valid argument to prefer string keys in some applications.

Comment: @akuhn With the frozen-string pragma, immutable strings of the same value are the same object.  See: http://crivelaro.me/programming/2016/01/01/new-in-ruby-2-3-immutable_strings.html

Comment: It does not, just try `a = 'hello'; b = 'world'; 10.times { p (a + b).freeze.object_id }` this blog post is not well informed and misleading.

Comment: @akuhn The answer is correct.  The frozen strings pragma is something different than just freezing a string.  It is a special comment (`# frozen_string_literal: true`) you put at the top of the file that causes all strings literals to be frozen by default.  This prama does indeed cause string literals with the same value to be the same object.  In some future version of Ruby, the pragma will become the default: That is what the answer means by "With frozen string support, at some point symbols and strings will be identical."

Comment: I guess what you mean to say is "with frozen string support, at some point DYNAMIC symbols and LITERAL strings will be identical" but even then that's speculative and currently only true insofar as both are interned.