# In Ruby, how to choose whether a symbol or string to be used in a given scenario?

Tags: ruby

I see this answer in various websites:

> If the contents (the sequence of characters) of the object are
>   important, use a string   If the identity of the object is important,
>   use a symbol

But, what does this actually mean? Please give  me an explanation which even a layman can understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a string and a symbol in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255078/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-symbol-in-ruby)

Comment: symbols are nice for hash keys because there's a concise syntax. They're also used in metaprogramming, and many functions require symbol arguments. Other than that, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447537/using-ruby-symbols/11447568#11447568

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/41516232

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = :foo
b = :foo
```

`a` and `b` refer to the same object in memory (same identity)

```
a.object_id # => 898908
b.object_id # => 898908
```

Strings behave differently

```
a = 'foo'
b = 'foo'

a.object_id # => 70127643805220
b.object_id # => 70127643805200
```

So, you use strings to store data and perform manipulations on data (replace characters or whatnot) and you use symbols to name things (keys in a hash or something). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11447568/125816) for more use cases for symbol.

Comment: It's also important to *not* use symbols when you're dealing with user supplied data, like arbitrary JSON keys or parameter names. In older versions of Ruby these were never garbage collected and presented a Denial of Service attack surface. Using symbols for frequently repeated things that you control is a good idea. They're also faster to compare.